# Weighted sum of absolute values is a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

How can I prove that $p: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geqslant0}$
\begin{equation}
  p(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert x_i\rvert,\quad w_i>0
\end{equation}
is a norm.

I immediately answered my own question and the proof to be verified is in my own answer.
I apologize if this is not a good way to pose the proof verification questions.

Comment: You have used the `proof-verification` tag. Where is your proof that you want someone else to verify?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: I thought it would be ok to answer my own question for this purpose. The proof is in the answer.

Comment: The tags are about the question, not about the possible answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am removing proof verification tag if it helps. I was really hoping I get the downvotes or upvotes on the answer and not on the question.

Comment: I have cancelled my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition) of the norm the function

1. has to satisfy the triangle inequality
   \begin{equation}
   p(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert x_i + y_i\rvert \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert x_i\rvert + \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert y_i\rvert = p(\mathbf{x})+p(\mathbf{y})
   \end{equation}
2. has to be absolutely homogeneous
   \begin{equation}
   p(a\mathbf{x})= \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert ax_i\rvert = \sum_{i=1}^{n}w_i\lvert a\rvert\lvert x_i\rvert = \lvert a\rvert p(\mathbf{x})
   \end{equation}
3. and $p(\mathbf{x})=0 \Rightarrow \mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$.

In order to prove the third point lets prove the [the contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive) $\mathbf{x}\neq \mathbf{0} \Rightarrow p(\mathbf{x}) > 0$.
If any of the elements of the vector is different than zero $x_i\neq0$ then its weighted absolute value is positive $w_i\lvert x_i\rvert >0$.
The function is a sum of non-negative values which can not be equal to zero if one of its elements is positive.
This proves the contrapositive.

Comment: there you go   ..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Since $||x||_1$ is the famous $1$-norm and $x\to wx$ is a linear transformation where $w=\text{diag}(w_1,\cdots ,w_n)$, hence the result.